# Telerik RadChart bar chart labels not lining up correctly

Tags: radchart

In this bar chart, some of the labels aren't lining up correctly. Short of making the bars thicker, what can I do fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to make the bars thicker.